# NoMethodError while executing app.rb in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, sequel, nomethoderror

When I try to run program in Rubymine I got the NoMethodError.

There are description of this error:

```
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/sequel-4.11.0/lib/sequel/plugins/json_serializer.rb:166:in `<module:ClassMethods>': undefined method `inherited_instance_variables' for Sequel::Plugins:Module (NoMethodError)


/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/sequel-4.11.0/lib/sequel/plugins/json_serializer.rb:166:in `<module:ClassMethods>': undefined method `inherited_instance_variables' for Sequel::Plugins:Module (NoMethodError)
from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/sequel-4.11.0/lib/sequel/plugins/json_serializer.rb:136:in `<module:JsonSerializer>'
from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/sequel-4.11.0/lib/sequel/plugins/json_serializer.rb:111:in `<module:Plugins>'
from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/sequel-4.11.0/lib/sequel/plugins/json_serializer.rb:4:in `<module:Sequel>'
from /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/sequel-4.11.0/lib/sequel/plugins/json_serializer.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/admin/Documents/Projects/marsu-schedule-server/json_generator/json_generator.rb:4:in `require'
from /Users/admin/Documents/Projects/marsu-schedule-server/json_generator/json_generator.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/admin/Documents/Projects/marsu-schedule-server/msu_server.rb:10:in `require'
from /Users/admin/Documents/Projects/marsu-schedule-server/msu_server.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/admin/Documents/Projects/marsu-schedule-server/app.rb:5:in `require'
from /Users/admin/Documents/Projects/marsu-schedule-server/app.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Executing in terminal (MAC OS X) gives the same error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what code are you running?

Comment: We can't help you unless you give us a minimal example of your code that demonstrates the problem. As is, the problem is probably somewhere in how you're calling the JSON class, probably in a `to_json` method.